# quicksort implementation for custom vector&string class

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I am working on implementing a sort for homework. After implementing insertion sort, I wanted to do a little more and started implementing quicksort, and ran into a problem.

Any sort I implement should read in list of words from a file, tokenize each word deliminated by white space, then organize the list of words from shortest to longest, then in alphabetical order within. For instance, if the input list of words are

```
argument coding love waterbottle physics graduate pressure winning dream achieve can greatness madness clarity bliss b d e r
```

The output should be

```
b
d
e
r
can
love
bliss
dream
coding
achieve
clarity
madness
physics
winning
argument
graduate
pressure
greatness
waterbottle
```

Using insertion sort worked fine. However using quicksort, the result I receive is wierd.

```
canument
baning
dream
lovembottle
winninge
graduate
pressure
physicse
achievettle
waterbottle
codingess
madnessss
blissss
greatness
clarityss
d
e
rrgument
argument
```

The vector being unsorted is wierd, but I can't quite understand why the mix up of word would happen.

After reading about quicksort, this is what I have implemented.

```
template<class T>
int Vector<T>::partition(int first, int last)
{
  //pivot is index location at the end of vector
  int pivot = last;
  //low is first index location element of the vector
  int low = first;
  //high is last index before pivot
  int high =pivot-1;
  //as long as the value of data at index low is less than data at pivot, increment low
  while(data[low] < data[pivot])
  {
      low++;
  }
  //when the data at low count is higher than data at pivot index
  if(data[low] > data[pivot])
  {
      //as long as the data at high index has greater value than value at pivot index, decrement the high counter
      while(data[high] > data[pivot])
      {
          high--;
      }
      //when data at high index is less than data at pivot index,
      //swap the data at low index with data at high index
      if(data[high] < data[pivot])
      {
          T temp = data[low];
          data[low] = data[high];
          data[high] = temp;
      }
  }
  //when low index is == high index
  //swap data at high with data at pivot. Now the pivot data is in correct
  //index location. Return the location of pivot with index of high(where pivot now is)
  T pi = data[high];
  data[high] = data[pivot];
  data[pivot] = pi;
  return high;
}

template<class T>
void Vector<T>::quickSort(int start, int end)
{
  //if the start index is lower than end index,
  if(start < end)
  {
      //the index of pivot is given from the partition function
      int pi = partition(start, end);
      //recursive call for left half and right half of the remaining
      //elements.
      quickSort(start, pi-1);
      quickSort(pi+1, end);
  }
}
```

I am puzzled because I do not know what is causing this problem. Should I look at my String class? Vector class? or is this a problem in implementation?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You haven't shown us enough to fully debug this (what type is "T"?)  At a guess, your comparison operator for T is wrong, and your assignment operator for it isn't right, either.